# Why the editText doesn't show the user input in Python class?

Tags: python, button, pyqt5, editline

I have a Python class that display a window that includes 2 text filed and 2 buttons.

Where the user enter a string in the first edit text and on click on the (**open button**) the second edit text will display the user input.

The problem is that on the click on the button there is nothing displayed in the text filed.

## Code:

```
'''
1- import the libraries from the converted file
2- import the converted file 
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pathmsgbox 
import os 
import pathlib

class path_window(pathmsgbox.Ui_PathMSGbox):


    def __init__(self,windowObject ):
        self.windowObject = windowObject
        self.setupUi(windowObject)
        self.windowObject.show()
        self.getText()


    '''
    get the userInput  from the EditLine
    '''   

    def getText(self):
        inputUser = self.pathEditLine.text()
        outPutUser = self.outputPathName.setText(inputUser)
        print(outPutUser)

    def puchBtn(self):
        openButton = self.PathOpenBtn.clicked.connect(self.getText)    
'''
function that exit from the system after clicking "cancel"
'''
def exit():
    sys.exit()

'''
define the methods to run only if this is the main module deing run
the name take __main__ string only if its the main running script and not imported 
nor being a child process
'''
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    PathMSGbox = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    pathUi = path_window(PathMSGbox)
    pathUi.pathCancelBtn.clicked.connect(exit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not connecting your clicked button event to the function - the binding is in a function that is never called.

Simply connect your button in the class initialization:

```
class path_window(pathmsgbox.Ui_PathMSGbox):


    def __init__(self,windowObject ):
        self.windowObject = windowObject
        self.setupUi(windowObject)
        self.windowObject.show()
        self.PathOpenBtn.clicked.connect(self.getText)
        self.getText()
```

Comment: i tried your answer it works but still  the print (outPutUser) display None in the console

Comment: when you call `print(outPutUser)` you are actually printing the `.setText` return, which is correctly `None`. If you want to print the input of the user, call `print(inputUser)`

Comment: i have another question how to make the user enter a path for a directory  where the open Button will open the entered path  after it check it if exist

Comment: you may want to use `os.path.exist(path)` to verify if a path exist, and `os.listdir(path)` to get a list of the files inside that directory, but it's a pretty long answer. Resolve this question and open a more specific answer on this